# Почта РФ, FindByCode

Tags: java, api, rest, android-volley

Есть [url](https://www.pochta.ru/portal-portlet/delegate/postoffice-api/method/offices.find.byCode?postalCode=127287).

Можно передать параметр `postalCode` и в ответе инфа по почтовому отделению. Очень крутая штука, но не очень понятно, как прикрутить ее в Android приложение?

Я использую Volley. Как можно правильно прикрутить?

Пока то, что понятно:
Стрелять нужно GET, postalCode - нужно передавать в параметрах.
Что нужно отправлять в заголовках, что бы взлетело?

Answer (score 0):

Этот сервис Почты РФ возращает информацию в формате JSON. То есть вам необходим парсер JSON.

Comment: Так нету проблем распарсить. Проблема вообще получить данные. Я получают 400 ошибку. И подозреваю, что от меня, ждут что-то в заголовке , но не понимаю, что.

Comment: @ДимаГуманов, добавьте эту информацию в запрос

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, какую информацию?

Comment: @ДимаГуманов, Вы не указали в вопросе, что получаете 400-сотую ошибку, а также не указали, что для этого делали